AWS RDS taking snapshots outside the backup window
I administer an AWS RDS SQL Server instance, with a backup window of 22:00-22:30 UTC and a retention period of 35 days.

I have noticed some peculiarities:

There are 55 automatic snapshots currently stored, not 35 as I would expect. 20 of the days seem to have 2 snapshots rather than 1.
19 of those 55 snapshots have start times outside the backup window. If they were a couple of minutes outside I could cut AWS some slack, but these times are all over the place.

17/05/2024 03:01:05
17/05/2024 11:26:10
17/05/2024 14:35:32
20/05/2024 12:36:04
21/05/2024 15:40:30
23/05/2024 17:06:00
24/05/2024 23:05:21
27/05/2024 22:45:26
28/05/2024 09:05:34
29/05/2024 17:50:23
01/06/2024 16:00:29
04/06/2024 12:50:47
06/06/2024 04:40:31
06/06/2024 05:30:47
08/06/2024 07:05:29
08/06/2024 16:40:31
08/06/2024 18:30:40
12/06/2024 16:35:40
17/06/2024 09:11:00

This is a problem because snapshots that start outside the backup window have been interfering with SQL Server native backups that start at other times of day. I really need all snapshots to start within the backup window. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Honestly, if your issue is with when your AWS RDS instance is scheduling it's backups as opposed to your native SQL Server backups, then your best bet for help is contacting AWS support.

import boto3

# Configuration
rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
db_instance_identifier = 'your-db-instance-identifier'
retention_days = 35

# List automated snapshots
snapshots = rds_client.describe_db_snapshots(
    DBInstanceIdentifier=db_instance_identifier,
    SnapshotType='automated'
)['DBSnapshots']

# Sort snapshots by creation time
snapshots.sort(key=lambda x: x['SnapshotCreateTime'], reverse=True)

# Keep only the latest `retention_days` snapshots
for snapshot in snapshots[retention_days:]:
    snapshot_id = snapshot['DBSnapshotIdentifier']
    print(f"Deleting snapshot: {snapshot_id}")
    rds_client.delete_db_snapshot(DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_id)


This doesn't answer the actual question, which is how to prevent snapshots out of the intended maintenance window. What this Python snippet does is that it deletes snapshots older than 35 days.
